# Word Chain Solver

Tags: kotlin

"Write a program that solves word-chain puzzles.

The challenge is to build a chain of words, starting with one particular word and ending with another. Successive entries must all be real words, and each can differ from the previous word by just one letter. "

[*Source*](http://codekata.com/kata/kata19-word-chains/).

Please give me feedback regarding good coding standards.

```
import java.io.File

typealias Word = String

fun main(arg: Array<String>) {
    val chain = WordChains("ruby", "code")
    chain.fChain()
}

class WordChains(private val initial: Word,
                 private val final: Word,
                 private val maxNoProgress: Int = 4) {

    private val wordLength = if (initial.length == final.length) initial.length
    else throw IllegalArgumentException("Word lengths are not equal.")
    private val finalChars = final.toCharArray()
    private val dictionary = File("dict.text")
            .readLines()
            .filter { it.length == wordLength }
            .map { it.toCharArray() }
            .filter { it.all { it in 'a'..'z' } }

    data class Chain(val words: List<WordAndDistance>, var noProgressCount: Int = 0)
    data class WordAndDistance(val charArray: CharArray, val distance: Int)

    fun fChain(chainList: List<Chain> = createChainList()) {
        val noWanderers =
                chainList.filter { it.noProgressCount < maxNoProgress }
        with(noWanderers) {
            if (isEmpty()) kotlin.run { println("List<Chain> is empty."); return }
            val completed = filter { it.words.last().distance == 1 }
            with(completed) {
                if (isNotEmpty()) {
                    printWords(suffix = final)
                    return
                }
            }
            fChain(mapNeighbours())
        }
    }

    private fun List<Chain>.mapNeighbours(): List<Chain> {
        return dictionary.flatMap { word -> filter { it.isNeighbour(word) }.map { it.append(word) } }
    }

    private fun Chain.append(word: CharArray): Chain {
        val newDistance = word.diff(finalChars)
        val newList = words + WordAndDistance(word, newDistance)
        val progressMade = newDistance < words.last().distance
        return copy(words = newList,
                noProgressCount = if (progressMade) noProgressCount else noProgressCount + 1)

    }

    private fun Chain.isNeighbour(word: CharArray): Boolean {
        return words.last().charArray.diff(word) <= 1
    }

    private fun CharArray.diff(word: CharArray): Int {
        return wordLength - filterIndexed { i, char -> char == word[i] }.size
    }

    private fun createChainList(chars: CharArray = initial.toCharArray()): List<Chain> {
        val wordAndDistance = WordAndDistance(chars, chars.diff(finalChars))
        val chain = Chain(words = listOf(wordAndDistance))
        return listOf<Chain>(chain)
    }

    private fun List<Chain>.printWords(suffix: String = "") {
        forEach { it.words.forEach { print(it.charArray.joinToString("") + ", ") }
            ;print(suffix)
            ; println() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Readability Improvements:**

```
private fun List<Chain>.mapNeighbours(): List<Chain> {
    return dictionary.flatMap { word -> filter { it.isNeighbour(word) }.map { it.append(word) } }
}

private fun Chain.append(word: CharArray): Chain {
    val newDistance = word.diff(finalChars)
    val newList = words + WordAndDistance(word, newDistance)
    val progressMade = newDistance < words.last().distance
    return copy(words = newList,
            noProgressCount = if (progressMade) noProgressCount else noProgressCount + 1)

}

private fun Chain.isNeighbour(word: CharArray): Boolean {
    return words.last().charArray.diff(word) <= 1
}
```

Refactored To--->

```
private fun List<Chain>.mapNeighbours(): List<Chain> {
    return dictionary.flatMap { word -> filterNeighbour(word).map { it + word } }
}

private operator fun Chain.plus(word: CharArray): Chain{
    val newDistance = word.diff(finalChars)
    val progressMade = newDistance < words.last().distance
    return copy(words = words + WordAndDistance(word, newDistance),
            noProgressCount = if (progressMade) noProgressCount else noProgressCount + 1)
}

private fun List<Chain>.filterNeighbour(word: CharArray): List<Chain> {
    return filter { it.words.last().charArray.diff(word) <= 1 }
}
```

---

```
private fun List<Chain>.printWords(suffix: String = "") {
            forEach { it.words.forEach { print(it.charArray.joinToString("") + ", ") }
                ;print(suffix)
                ; println() }
        }
    }
```

Refactored to---->

```
private fun List<Chain>.printWords(suffix: String = "") {
    forEach {
        for (word in it.words) { 
            print("${word.charArray.joinToString("")}, ") 
        }
        print("$suffix\n") 
    }
}
```